# Get WPF TabItem container from UserControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls, tabitem

I am setting the content of a UserControl, SIASystemTab, to a TabItem, ConfigTab.  How do you access the TabItem from the UserControl using code behind?  I would like to reuse the methods in the TabItem from multiple UserControls.

```
var subSystem = new SIASystemTab(opCo);
var configTab = new ConfigTab()
{
    Header = "New Header*",
    Content = subSystem
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to create a property in SIASystemTab like this

```
    public ConfigTab myConfigTab {get; set;}
```

Then assign the ConfigTab instance to this property

```
   subSystem.myConfigTab = configTab;
```

Later on u can use this as per your need

Comment: Did you mean public ConfigTab ConfigTab  {get; set;} ?  I got a compiler error otherwise.

Comment: @techmakin: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @mm8 Rahul's solution is easier to implement in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the `Content` property of the `UserControl` to `ConfigTab`:

```
var tab = this.Content as ConfigTab;
var siaSystemTab = tab.Content;
```